# ANT - JavaFX complex build.xml

Tags: java, svn, ant, javafx, compilation

I have a shared repository containing 5 .java files. ("d:rep/trunk/src")

I have a test folder for a JavaFX project, where I test the new codes by changing the files in the "src/" and running the JavaFX by compiling them from NetBeans. (d:test/JavaFXproject/src/gui/")

I am looking for the command which I could use to run all the JavaFX package possibly with the help of ant.

Comment: To learn how to use Ant, start with the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/).  A full Ant tutorial is too long for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I already searched answers in the documentation I just didn't find what I searched. 
I think my question was quite specificed, not to get a "documentation is your friend" especially in a tech-forum. I can write a build.xml which copies the files from the source to the destination, all I need is the lines which compiles the JavaFX project from the destination.

Comment: The Ant tasks which compile and run Java code have the same names as the corresponding JDK command-line tools: [javac](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) and [java](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

Comment: In case of JavaFX package the easiest way is to use "jfxsa-run" which is predefined. That was the one I needed, hopefully it will be a help to you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of trying I finally figured out how to mix the .bat file and the ANT in an easy way:

```
SET sourceFolder= D:\REPOSITORY\.....
SET testFolder= D:\TEST\....src\
SET testRunFolder = D:\\TEST\...

SET excludeFiles = build.bat

robocopy %sourceFolder% %testFolder%  /e /xf %excludeFiles%

echo Copy has finished

cd %testFolder%
ant -f %testRunFolder% jfxsa-run

echo Build has finished
```

This script is now copy the files to the right place and send them to compile and run.